# Both if and else statements executing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this query in my sql

```
if (select count(*) from sys.columns where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'CLIENT_STATUS')) = 4
    insert into CLIENT_STATUS select 'NA', 'Inactive', 0, 0    --old version
else 
    insert into CLIENT_STATUS select 'NA', 'Inactive', 0, 0, 1 --new version
```

The result of `select count(*) from sys.columns where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'CLIENT_STATUS')` is 4, however it always appears to be executing the 5 parameter `else` version of the query.

What am I doing wrong with my if statement?

**UPDATE:**

It appears to be running both statments because if I do

```
if (select count(*) from sys.columns where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'CLIENT_STATUS')) = 5
    insert into CLIENT_STATUS select 'NA', 'Inactive', 0, 0, 1 --new version
else 
    insert into CLIENT_STATUS select 'NA', 'Inactive', 0, 0    --old version
```

I get the same error but now it says it is doing the first statement.

**UPDATE2:**
Mikael Eriksson had the correct answer, I changed my code to this to fix it.

```
if ((select count(*) from sys.columns where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'CLIENT_STATUS')) = 5)
    execute ('insert into CLIENT_STATUS select ''NA'', ''Inactive'', 0, 0, 1') --new version
else
    execute ('insert into CLIENT_STATUS select ''NA'', ''Inactive'', 0, 0')    --old version
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the error when SQL Server compiles your statements.

With this table

```
create table TestTable(ID int)
```

Try to run this statement

```
if 1 = 1
  insert into TestTable values (1)
else
  insert into TestTable values(1, 2)
```

Result:

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Clearly the second statement will never be executed but it will be compiled.

Comment: Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: @Scott – One way would be to build your insert statement dynamically. Can't think of something else.

Comment: (1) Branched code, call one or the either sub-proc based on column count. (2) Stick a default on the 5th column if it will always the same under these circumstances. Alas, like dynamic SQL, these feel pretty kludgy.

Comment: I added the way to fix it to my main post, if you want post your example to this answer seance you are the one who gave me the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with your parenthesis, you close your if statement and then compare that to 5.

You could try this for debugging:

```
declare @myCount as int
select @myCount = select count(*) from sys.columns where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'CLIENT_STATUS';
print @myCount

if (@myCount = 5)
    insert into CLIENT_STATUS select 'NA', 'Inactive', 0, 0, 1 --new version
else 
    insert into CLIENT_STATUS select 'NA', 'Inactive', 0, 0    --old version
```

This will help you ensure the value you're getting from the select.

Comment: Adding the declare does not change anything.

Comment: Also I tried adding the begin/end set and that does not change it.

Comment: The declaring wasn't going to change anything, but check the output... what value was printed in the messages tab (assuming you run this in SSMS

Comment: it outputs 4 when i run the first 3 lines but i errors out right away and never displays the number when i run the whole batch. I think @Mikael Eriksson is right, this is a compiler issue not a run time issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reviving an old question, but I just had an issue where I didn't want to compile the ELSE statement if it never reaches it and found that the dynamic SQL advice above no longer works. What I found is that using the GOTO command I could avoid compiling the ELSE statement if it's not required. Here's an example:

```
IF (1 = 1) 
    GOTO SUCCESS;
ELSE GOTO ERROR;

ERROR:
    PRINT 'Oh no, an error'
    SELECT 1 + 'A'
SUCCESS:
    PRINT 'Yay no errors'
```

This will never error out, as the ERROR: branch will never be compiled.

Keep in mind that if you don't want to break the execution at an error like I did, you'll have to use GOTO again to skip the SUCCESS: branch. For example:

```
IF (1 <> 1) 
    GOTO SUCCESS;
ELSE GOTO ERROR;

ERROR:
    PRINT 'Oh no, an error'
    GOTO FINAL
SUCCESS:
    PRINT 'Yay no errors'
FINAL:
    PRINT 'Oh well'
```

Returns:

```
Oh no, an error
Oh well
```